# "git commit -a" causes "subl -w: subl: command not found"

Tags: macos, git, sublimetext

i am not sure what is causing this problem but i am having problems using git. It seems sublime is somehow interfering. Does perhaps anybody know how to solve this problem?

I am running OSX 10.9.3.

```
git version
git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)

git commit -a
subl -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Comment: How are you telling git to use sublime text as an editor?

Comment: I did not tell git to use sublime. As far as i remember i installed sublime and the xcode command line utilities which i believe included git.

Comment: What is in the [core] section of ~/.gitconfig

Comment: [core]
  editor = subl -w

Comment: @Susan, please write it down as an answer. This way other people can find your solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that git commit is trying to use an editor to allow you to create a commit message. The editor for git is possibly overridden in is set in your `~/.gitconfig` file. There will be a `[core]` section which sets the editor

e.g. for Sublime Text

```
[core]
  ...
  editor = subl -w   
  ...
```

remove the editor line to make the default editor go back to the shell's default editor